# Getting random BSOD Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, bsod

I have created this acc on superuser to ask you this question, I am at the end of my nerves. Computer is getting random BSOD once a day...this is so far, what have i done...

OS: Windows 7 64 bit

> run memecheck86+ 6 passes on each stick(4x2 gb RAM stick) no error
>
> run chkdsk no error
>
> unistall AVG install Microsoft Security Essentials

Here is Minidump

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1k44jtvap5cja87/minidump.rar

Comment: it's possible that you got virus but if was you i were going to test my pc with a linux os on USB or some thing to make sure if everything works fine or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dumps show RAM issues. Mabe you use wrong RAM timings for your `takeMS DIMM DDR3-1333 (TMS4GB364E081139EM)`.

Download and run the tool [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), go to the `SPD` and `memory` tab and verify that the current RAM Speed and the Timings match to the values that you see in the SPD tab. If your RAM run at CR (Command Rate) 1T, change the value into 2T in the BIOS.